# Count and group rows for each 24 hour period in sql

Tags: sql, presto

I want to get count of each day rows from the first event till next 24 hours grouped for every 24 hours. I tried lots of approaches but couldn't figure out without using loop. I want to do it without actually using loop because the sql server i am using doesn't support loop statement. So far i was able to join them and get i am thinking alone the side of using `LAG` or to keep track of 24 hours from first event but couldn't get far.

```
event_at,id,event_log_id
2024-01-17 10:22:20.000,1,1
2024-01-17 11:40:04.000,2,2
2024-01-18 11:18:50.000,3,3
2024-01-18 11:18:51.000,4,4
2024-01-18 11:18:52.000,5,5
2024-01-18 11:39:03.000,6,6
2024-01-18 14:17:48.000,7,7
```

Result i expected, from the first event for 24 hours for date 17 the event count is 2 and for next 24 hours its 5

```
event_at,count
2024-01-17 2
2024-01-18 5
```

Some experiment i tried with lag but couldn't get far

```
WITH lagged_data AS (
  SELECT
    "event_at",
    LAG("event_at") OVER (ORDER BY "event_at") AS prev_timestamp
  FROM
    "table"
     where ** and DATE("event_at") BETWEEN DATE '2024-01-01' AND DATE '2024-01-18'
)
SELECT
  "event_at",
  prev_timestamp AS period_start,
  COUNT(*) AS row_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    "event_at",
    LAG("event_at") OVER (ORDER BY "event_at") AS prev_timestamp,
    CASE
      WHEN LAG(DATE("event_at")) OVER (ORDER BY "event_at") IS NULL
        OR DATE("event_at") != LAG(DATE("event_at")) OVER (ORDER BY "event_at") THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS date_changed
  FROM
    "table"
     where ** is not null and DATE("event_at") BETWEEN DATE '2024-01-01' AND DATE '2024-01-18'
) lagged_with_date_change
WHERE
  (date_diff('second', prev_timestamp, "event_at") <= 86400 AND date_changed = 1)
  OR date_changed = 1  -- To include the first row of each date
GROUP BY
  "event_at", prev_timestamp, date_changed
ORDER BY
  "event_at";
```

For eg this data

```
2024-01-17 11:40:04.000 2   2
2024-01-18 11:18:50.000 3   3
2024-01-18 11:18:51.000 4   4
2024-01-18 11:18:52.000 5   5
2024-01-18 11:39:03.000 6   6

2024-01-18 14:17:48.000 7   7
2024-01-18 14:17:48.000 8   8

2024-01-19 14:17:48.000 10  10
2024-01-19 14:17:48.000 11  11
2024-01-19 15:17:48.000 12  12
2024-01-19 15:17:48.000 13  13
```

Should return: 5, 2, 4

EDIT: I think i made a mistake in understanding the logic but with few more sample testcases. I figure out this https://dbfiddle.uk/Xi0GiYQr
is more closer and correct with new testcases.

I am trying to rewrite the same for presto where only a single SQL statement is allowed and recursive cte isn't supported unfortunately.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; [edit] your question to tag properly, please.

Comment: You'll need a loop or a recursive query.

Comment: I agree but loop isn't possible its Presto. Is this still doable in sql

Comment: If I understand correctly; if you deleted the first row, the results would be 5 and 1? (5 events from 2024-01-17 11:40, and then 1 more event from 2024-01-18 11:40?) If so, are you always expecting two rows of output? One for the first 24h and one for the second 24h?  If so, would two columns be acceptable instead?

Comment: @MatBailie yup thats correct, its grouped for each 24 hours.

Comment: "each 24 hours" can mean calendar day, can imply an arbitrary number of days (not just two). *Please be more specific.* Are you always and only interested in 48 hours of data, starting from the first event, and split in to two 24 hour groups?  *(In your example case `2024-11-17 10:22:20` to  `2024-11-18 10:22:20` to `2024-11-19 10:22:20`?)*

Comment: Actually, I will be running the query on multiple duration not just 48 hours of data so could be for a year too let's say from 2023-01-17 to 2024-01-17. but splitting from the first event from selected data every 24 hours. I can edit the question with more data.

Comment: Added new data to reflect the possible query

Comment: You truly want your days going forward to be arbitrarily defined by the time of day the first one happened to fall?

Comment: yeah, basically i want to collect all events that happened at x time event + any other events collected at (x + 24 hours) into one group and recursively for all the groups.

Comment: It's the "recursively for all the groups" part that's still unclear. Take a look here and let me know which version has the result you need: https://dbfiddle.uk/kibYLSki

Comment: @shawnt00 actually now i see the second recursive query giving me the result i wanted because its taking care of missing dates and not adding those. wondering if it could be done in simple way like the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [prestodb manual](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.285/functions/datetime.html) is pretty vague on how `date_diff()` in particular works.

`DATE_DIFF(day, '2024-01-17 11:40:04', '2024-01-18 11:18:50.000')` could return one of two values...

- `0` because the second value is less than a whole day after the first value
- `1` because the second value is one ***calendar*** date after the first value

You want it to return `0`, but if it doesn't you can use...

- `DATE_DIFF('second', '2024-01-17 11:40:04', '2024-01-18 11:18:50.000') / 86400`

Given that, you can simply use...

```
SELECT
  DATE_ADD('day', offset_days, first_event_at),
  COUNT(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT
    MIN(event_at) OVER ()  AS first_event_at,
    DATE_DIFF(
      'second', -- presto accepts varchar for unit
      MIN(event_at) OVER (),
      event_at
    )
    /
    86400                  AS offset_days
  FROM
    your_table
)
  offset_calc
GROUP BY
  offset_days,
  first_event_at
ORDER BY
  1
```

Example using SQL Server Syntax (as I can't find a presto fiddle site):

- https://dbfiddle.uk/PAmdRBJP

Comment: This is much easier than using a RECURSIVE CTE as I did in my answer. Thank you teaching me something new!

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome looks like its working. DATE_DIFF and DATE_ADD accept a varchar for day and second so needs to add that fix.

Comment: I wish i could add bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RECURSIVE CTE` for this.

**Important Notes:**

- I started working on this before you specified Presto; initially I read your post as `SQL Server` so that is what the example is generated from. **You can modify the query syntax to whichever DBMS you are using.**
- I added a few extra dates to further test the query.

**The How:**

1. Assign a unique `ROW NUMBER` to each event in the `CTE_EVENTS_BASE` table. This is the prep work for the CTE.
2. Create a `RECURSIVE CTE` that calculates the hour different between the current and next row (`HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT`. We then add these hours to a running sum of hours (`RS_HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT`). When the running sum exceeds 24 hours we reset the `RS_HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT` back to zero.
3. Assign each event to a `EVENT_GROUP_NUM`. We start at a GROUP_NUM of 1 and then increment this each time the `RS_HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT` exceeds 24 hours.
4. Finally, we return the first EVENT_AT and a count of Events based on the `EVENT_GROUP_NUM`

**SQL FIDDLE:**
[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=8d247661-db60-4716-9963-c3546abf0abc)

**QUERY:**

```
CREATE TABLE events_tbl (
  event_at DATETIME,
  id INTEGER,
  event_log_id INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO events_tbl
  (event_at, id, event_log_id)
VALUES
  ('2024-01-17 10:22:20.000', '1', '1'),
  ('2024-01-17 11:40:04.000', '2', '2'),
  ('2024-01-18 11:18:50.000', '3', '3'),
  ('2024-01-18 11:18:51.000', '4', '4'),
  ('2024-01-18 11:18:52.000', '5', '5'),
  ('2024-01-18 11:39:03.000', '6', '6'),
  ('2024-01-18 14:17:48.000', '7', '7'),
  ('2024-01-19 18:01:03.000', '8', '8'),
  ('2024-01-19 20:22:01.000', '9', '9'),
  ('2024-01-19 22:39:03.000', '10', '10'),
  ('2024-01-20 01:01:01.000', '11', '11'),
  ('2024-01-21 00:01:01.000', '12', '12');
 
WITH CTE_EVENTS_BASE AS
  (SELECT A.EVENT_AT,
          A.ID,
          A.EVENT_LOG_ID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                             ORDER BY A.EVENT_AT) AS ROW_NUM
   FROM EVENTS_TBL A),
     RECUR_CTE_EVENTS AS
  (SELECT A.EVENT_AT,
          A.ID,
          A.EVENT_LOG_ID,
          A.ROW_NUM,
          CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(22, 5)) AS HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT,
          CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(22, 5)) AS RS_HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT,
          1 AS EVENT_COUNT,
   1 AS EVENT_GROUP_NUM
   FROM CTE_EVENTS_BASE A
   WHERE A.ROW_NUM = 1
   UNION ALL SELECT A.EVENT_AT,
                    A.ID,
                    A.EVENT_LOG_ID,
                    A.ROW_NUM,
                    /* GET THE HOURS SINCE LAST EVENT */
                    CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, B.EVENT_AT, A.EVENT_AT) / 3600.00 AS DECIMAL(22, 5)) AS HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT,
                    /* IF THE RUNNING SUM OF HOURS EXCEEDS 24 HOURS THEN RESET THE RUNNING SUM TO ZERO */
                    CAST(CASE
                        WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, B.EVENT_AT, A.EVENT_AT) / 3600.00 AS DECIMAL(22, 5)) + B.RS_HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT >= 24 THEN 0.00000
                        ELSE CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, B.EVENT_AT, A.EVENT_AT) / 3600.00 AS DECIMAL(22, 5)) + B.RS_HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT
                    END AS DECIMAL(22,5)) AS RS_HOURS_LAST_REQUEST,
                    /* EVENT COUNT EVERY 24 HOURS */
                    CASE
                        WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, B.EVENT_AT, A.EVENT_AT) / 3600.00 AS DECIMAL(22, 5)) + B.RS_HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT >= 24 THEN 1
                        ELSE b.EVENT_COUNT + 1
                    END AS EVENT_COUNT,
                    /* ASSIGN SAME EVENTS TO A GROUP */
                    CASE
                        WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND, B.EVENT_AT, A.EVENT_AT) / 3600.00 AS DECIMAL(22, 5)) + B.RS_HOURS_SINCE_LAST_EVENT >= 24 THEN b.EVENT_GROUP_NUM + 1
                        ELSE b.EVENT_GROUP_NUM
                    END AS EVENT_GROUP_NUM
                    
   FROM CTE_EVENTS_BASE A
   INNER JOIN RECUR_CTE_EVENTS B ON A.ROW_NUM = B.ROW_NUM + 1)

SELECT MIN(a.EVENT_AT) AS EVENT_AT, COUNT(a.ID) AS EVENT_COUNT
FROM RECUR_CTE_EVENTS a
GROUP BY a.EVENT_GROUP_NUM;
```

**OUTPUT:**

| EVENT_AT | EVENT_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-17 10:22:20.000 | 2 |
| 2024-01-18 11:18:50.000 | 5 |
| 2024-01-19 18:01:03.000 | 4 |
| 2024-01-21 00:01:01.000 | 1 |

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful i was trying something similar.

Comment: Is this still doable without recursive cte, i think this logic is fine but presto doesn't support recursion.

Comment: @Abhishek I'll try another approach. What was the issue with MatBallie's answer?

Comment: i edited some more data here: https://dbfiddle.uk/Xi0GiYQr https://dbfiddle.uk/Xi0GiYQr where first 4 are grouped correctly and missing dates are not counted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand correctly but I hope this helps you:

```
select 
 tag as event_at,
 count(tag) as count_nr /* i dont like use count as column name*/ 
from (
 select *,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), event_at ,120) as tag from events_tbl
) as t1 group by tag
```

based on your fiddle:

```
CREATE TABLE events_tbl (
  event_at DATETIME,
  id INTEGER,
  event_log_id INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO events_tbl
  (event_at, id, event_log_id)
VALUES
 ('2024-01-01 01:00:01', 1, 1),
 ('2024-01-01 02:00:01', 102, 102),
 ('2024-01-01 03:00:01', 112, 112),
 ('2024-01-01 04:00:01', 122, 122),
 ('2024-01-02 00:55:01', 123, 123),
 ('2024-01-03 00:59:59', 2, 2),
 ('2024-01-03 01:00:00', 3, 3),
 ('2024-01-03 01:00:01', 4, 4),
 ('2024-01-03 01:00:02', 5, 5),
 ('2024-01-03 01:00:03', 6, 6),
 ('2024-01-04 00:55:03', 6, 6),
 ('2024-02-01 00:00:00', 7, 7),
 ('2024-02-01 06:00:00', 8, 8),
 ('2024-02-01 12:00:00', 9, 9),
 ('2024-02-01 18:00:00', 10, 10),
 ('2024-02-02 00:00:00', 11, 11),
 ('2024-02-02 06:00:00', 12, 12),
 ('2024-02-02 12:00:00', 13, 13),
 ('2024-02-02 18:00:00', 14, 14),
 ('2024-02-03 00:00:00', 15, 15),
 ('2024-02-03 06:00:00', 16, 16);

select 
  tag as event_at,
  count(tag) as count_nr /* i dont like use count as column name*/ 
from (
  select *,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), event_at ,120) as tag from events_tbl
) as t1 group by tag
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself in a predicament where recursive CTEs are not upheld by Presto and your goal is to achieve this daunting task with just one SQL statement, fear not! You can employ the powerful combination of window functions alongside conditional aggregation to successfully compute the tally of events for every 24-hour cycle, starting from the very first event. To aid you in your quest, I present to you a meticulously crafted query that is poised to accomplish this feat.

```
SELECT
  date_trunc('day', event_at) AS period_start,
  COUNT(*) AS row_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    event_at,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY event_at) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('day', event_at) ORDER BY event_at) AS grp
  FROM
    your_table
) numbered_data
GROUP BY
  period_start, grp
ORDER BY
  period_start;
```

In this query, we utilize the disparity amongst two ROW_NUMBER() window functions to fabricate a distinctive identifier for grouping, which we call "grp". The divergence between the universal row number and the row number within each day is consistent for rows encompassed by a span of 24 hours. Subsequently, we compute the tally of occurrences during each 24-hour interval by grouping based on this identifier.

Please ensure that you substitute "your_table" with the real name of your table. The provided query assumes that the column "event_at" is of a TIMESTAMP or comparable type. Modify the data types and column names according to your specific situation if necessary.